Network Manager Issue - needs restart for ONLY 1 device
I am setting up my Lenovo laptop (with Ubuntu) for homelab. I am able to connect all my devices in the network using IP address of my laptop and port. However, from my phone (Galaxy Fold 6) I am only able to connect for some time and then the ping don't work (both way - laptop to phone and phone to laptop). However, it doesn't stop for other devices (laptops, tabs etc.). It only stops for this phone.
When I restart networkManager, it works for some time and then again stops.
My laptop has a static local IP: 192.168.1.101
My phone's IP is: 192.168.1.26 (mac address: cc:f9:f0:6c:54:4b)
UPDATE: I just observerd, this happens only when I connect to 5Ghz network of my router, it's not happening with 2.4GHz network (at least it didn't happen so far)
Attaching my Network Manager logs below:
Dec 24 13:34:27 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027467.0266] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,33) skip connectivity check due to no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:34:27 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027467.0266] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv4,32) check completed: LIMITED; no global route configured
Dec 24 13:34:27 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027467.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,33) check completed: NONE; no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:34:27 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Creating peer entry for cc:f9:f0:6c:54:4b
Dec 24 13:34:28 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Dialog Token in TPK M1 1
Dec 24 13:34:28 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: nl80211: kernel reports: key addition failed
Dec 24 13:34:28 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Failed to set TPK to the driver
Dec 24 13:34:29 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027469.7472] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:34:29 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027469.9372] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:34:31 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027471.8755] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:34:56 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027496.4526] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:34:58 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027498.7469] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv4,34) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Dec 24 13:34:58 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027498.7470] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv6,35) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Dec 24 13:34:58 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027498.7470] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv4,34) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Dec 24 13:34:58 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027498.7470] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv6,35) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv4,36) skip connectivity check due to no global route configured
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,37) skip connectivity check due to no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv4,36) check completed: LIMITED; no global route configured
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,37) check completed: NONE; no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.6271] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:34:59 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027499.8310] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:01 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027501.0602] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:01 ayush CRON[492243]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Dec 24 13:35:01 ayush CRON[492244]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec 24 13:35:01 ayush CRON[492243]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 24 13:35:04 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027504.6452] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:06 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027506.4868] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:25 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027525.2248] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:26 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027526.2462] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:30 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Creating peer entry for cc:f9:f0:6c:54:4b
Dec 24 13:35:30 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027530.2577] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:30 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027530.3102] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:31 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027531.2840] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:32 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Dialog Token in TPK M1 1
Dec 24 13:35:32 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: nl80211: kernel reports: key addition failed
Dec 24 13:35:32 ayush wpa_supplicant[1110]: TDLS: Failed to set TPK to the driver
Dec 24 13:35:35 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027535.3894] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:35 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027535.4752] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027536.3904] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c822] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Dec 24 13:35:36 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027536.7152] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:40 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027540.0343] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:35:40 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027540.0778] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027560.0791] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027560.1522] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c822] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Dec 24 13:36:00 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Dec 24 13:36:01 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027561.0281] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027562.7468] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv4,38) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027562.7469] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv6,39) skip connectivity check due to no carrier
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027562.7470] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv4,38) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027562.7470] connectivity: (enp1s0,IPv6,39) check completed: NONE; no carrier
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c822] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Dec 24 13:36:02 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Dec 24 13:36:03 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027563.0264] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv4,40) skip connectivity check due to no global route configured
Dec 24 13:36:03 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027563.0266] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,41) skip connectivity check due to no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:36:03 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027563.0266] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv4,40) check completed: LIMITED; no global route configured
Dec 24 13:36:03 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027563.0267] connectivity: (br-b60eca4d63ee,IPv6,41) check completed: NONE; no IP address configured
Dec 24 13:36:04 ayush kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
Dec 24 13:36:04 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 24 13:36:04 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c822] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Dec 24 13:36:04 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Dec 24 13:36:05 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027565.1428] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:05 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027565.1878] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:06 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027566.1792] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:06 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027566.3917] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:07 ayush kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Correctable error message received from 0000:02:00.0
Dec 24 13:36:07 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Correctable, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Dec 24 13:36:07 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c822] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Dec 24 13:36:07 ayush kernel: rtw_8822ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Dec 24 13:36:10 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027570.2734] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:10 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027570.3344] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:51 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027611.3380] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:55 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027615.3327] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:56 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027616.4578] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5807] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5807] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: received router advertisement at timestamp 183.291 seconds
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5807] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: router-data: next lifetime expiration will happen: in 600.000 seconds
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: neighbor discovery configuration changed [GARS]:
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   dhcp-level otherconf
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   hop limit      : 64
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   gateway fe80::1 pref low exp 1800.000
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   address 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484 exp 86400.000
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   route 2401:4900:1c30:34d1::/64 via fe80::1 pref high exp 86400.000
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   route 2401:4900:1c30:34d1::/64 via :: pref medium exp 86400.000
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5808] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]:   dns_server fe80::1 exp 600.000
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5809] ndisc[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: solicit: schedule sending next (slow) solicitation in about 538.971 seconds
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5810] l3cfg[746842304668b76d,ifindex=3]: obj-state: update: [3a39e85993f892fa, ip6-address, 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484/64 lft 86400sec pref 86400sec lifetime 183-183[86400,86400] dev 3 flags mngtmpaddr,noprefixroute src ndisc], nm-configured, in-platform (static: 1, dynamic: 0)
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5810] dns-mgr: (device_l3cd_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5810] dns-mgr: (device_l3cd_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5810] dns-mgr: (device_l3cd_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5811] platform: (wlp2s0) address: adding or updating IPv6 address: 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484/64 lft 86400sec pref 86400sec lifetime 183-0[86400,86400] dev 3 flags mngtmpaddr,noprefixroute src unknown
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5812] platform: (wlp2s0) signal: address 6 changed: 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484/64 lft 86400sec pref 86400sec lifetime 183-183[86400,86400] dev 3 flags mngtmpaddr,noprefixroute src kernel
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5812] l3cfg[746842304668b76d,ifindex=3]: obj-state: appeared in platform: [3a39e85993f892fa, ip6-address, 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484/64 lft 86400sec pref 86400sec lifetime 183-183[86400,86400] dev 3 flags mngtmpaddr,noprefixroute src ndisc], nm-configured, in-platform
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5812] platform: (wlp2s0) signal: address 6 changed: 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:6301:3c7a:3e32:1789/64 lft 86400sec pref 85994sec lifetime 183-183[85994,86400] dev 3 flags secondary src kernel
Dec 24 13:36:57 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027617.5812] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[3: 2401:4900:1c30:34d1:d550:293f:8331:c484]: success
Dec 24 13:37:00 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027620.4528] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:37:06 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027626.8066] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:37:08 ayush smartd[1000]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 73 to 72
Dec 24 13:37:08 ayush smartd[1000]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 27 to 28
Dec 24 13:37:10 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027630.7932] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec 24 13:37:10 ayush NetworkManager[491898]: <debug> [1735027630.9026] ndisc-lndp[0x5a0318a9edb0,"wlp2s0"]: processing libndp events


Is it a new Lenovo Laptop? It may worth it to try out the OEM kernel then.
